# How do you use c++ lambda's like c#

Tags: c#, c++, lambda

I have experience with c# lambdas and I'm trying to translate it into c++. For example take this c# method:

int sum(int one, int two) => one + two;

Does c++ have a shortcut like this, or do I need to specifically say return?

Comment: I don’t believe that use of => is or behaves like a lambda.

Comment: @zzxyz: You're right - an expression-bodied member re-uses the lambda operator, but is not a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

> Does c++ have a shortcut like this, or do I need to specifically say return?

C++ does not support that syntax. You'll have to use `return`.

The closest analogs I can think of in C++ are lambda functions and `inline` functions.

lambda function:

```
auto sum = [] (int one, int two) { return one + two; };
```

inline function:

```
int sum(int one, int two) { return one + two; };
```

Comment: I would neither use a lambda nor inferred return type for that.

Comment: You're right that C++ does not support this - it's an expression-bodied member. But the equivalent is not a C++ lambda.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, that's not a lambda in C#, but an "expression-bodied member" - i.e., just a shortcut way of writing a function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members

The equivalent in C++ is just a plain old method:

```
int sum(int one, int two)
{
    return one + two;
}
```